# Class' member variable gets assigned at runtime (via 'new') but doesn't persist

Tags: c++, qt

I've declared a member array to store the pointers for a bunch of Qt Control widgets (QLineEdit),

In the main code, I programmatically create these widgets and assign, however they are only accessible while the function is in scope:

```
    // MyGui.h
    class myGui : public QMainWindow, private Ui::uiFormWin
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
            MyGui(QMainWindow *parent = 0);
            Test();
        private:
            QTimer *pUiTimer;
            QLineEdit* le2T[ 32 ];        
        public slots:       
            void GuiUpdate(void);
    }

    // MyGui.c
    MyGui::MyGui(QMainWindow *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)  
    {
        // Create Objects and Assign
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 32; i++ ){
            le2T[ i ] = new QLineEdit (this);    
        }

        // This Displays fine:
        le2T [ 0 ]->setText ("Hello"); 

        // Setup Timer To Update Line Edit Later
        pUiTimer = new QTimer(this);
        pUiTimer->setInterval(100);
        connect(pUiTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(GuiUpdate()) );
    }

    void MyGui::GuiUpdate( void )
    {   
        // This next line causes Run-Time Crash  -- le2T[0] object is null!
        le2T [ 0 ]->setText ("World");  // Error
    }
```

Interestingly, even though they are no longer accessible, they still appear on the GUI.

I've tried making these QLineEdit objects as members variables in my class (instead of an array of pointers), but, accessing QLineEdit's member functions fails.. and Qt doesn't even auto-detect these as QLineEdit objects!

```
        .h
            QLineEdit le2T[ 32 ];   
        .cpp
        le2T[ 0 ].setText ("World");  //  Error
```

How can I create an array of widgets at run-time, and save as member variables so that they can be accessed from any method in the class?

Comment: which version of QT?

Comment: perhaps print out what `this` is inside `GuiUpdate` and check it is actually the right address

Comment: why does your source code have `QLineEdit* le2T[ 32 ];` but your snippet near the end has `QLineEdit le2T[ 32 ];` ?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.3, but I suspect this may be a general mis-understanding of C++ / scope thingy.   Inside GuiUpdate I can manipulate other aspects of the Gui Window, just not any of the control widgets created dynamically.   The snippet at the bottom is when I tried using QLineEdit member variables, instead of QLineEdit pointers

Comment: It could be a buffer overflow in some other part of your code that can inadvertently write on your le2T pointer array address. With the debug, you can check the content of your array before and after the timer call and check if the address remains the same.